# The product is incorrectly calculated in an assembly insert in the c language

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm doing an assembler insert to calculate the expression v_C. However, I came across the fact that x * (y + 2) is calculated incorrectly. Please tell me what my mistake is.

(x86 processor, visual studio compiler)

here is a part of the code:

```
char x, z;
short int y, v, v_as, v_C;
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

x = 0x72;
y = -0x78AC;
z = -0x7F;
v = 0x6B78;

v_C = (1 + x * (y + 2)) / (z - 1) + 1;

_asm
{
//числитель
mov ax, y;
add ax, 2;
mov bh, 0;
mov bl, x;
imul bx;
mov v_as, ax;//The end of the product result is saved in the ax

}
printf("Решение для x=bh, y=-3h, z=-1h:\nv_C= %d(в 10), v_C= %x(в 16)\nv_as= %d(в 10), v_as= %x(в 16)\nv= %d(в 10), v= %x(в 16)\n", v_C, v_C, v_as, v_as, v, v);
```

I tried to count without taking into account the sign, it didn't get any better

Comment: That asm correctly implements `(y+2) * (uint16_t)(uint8_t)x` with the result truncated to 16-bit.  (Which you declared as signed `short int`, so printing it will do sign-extension to 32-bit `int`.)  You haven't said what you got or what you think the correct result should be.

Comment: I need to get -3 521 460, but the output is -5 417 484.
So I need to correct the output? how to do it?

Comment: Note that as part of `v_C = (1 + x * (y + 2)) / (z - 1) + 1;`, the `x*(y+2)` inputs are promoted to `int` (presumably 32-bit int) by C's integer promotion rules for narrow types, so unlike your asm, it doesn't truncate the result to `int16_t`.  Also, that's a different expression involving `z` and more terms, so it's definitely not going to equal the `imul` result.  It involves a division, so the high bits of the product *do* matter; for add/sub/multiply, the low `n` bits of the result only depend on the low `n` bits of the inputs, but that's not the case for division or modulo.

Comment: From the multiply you're asking about? `0x72 * (-0x78AC + 2)` with signed 16-bit `imul` is `114 * -30890` (reg values 0x0072 and 0x8756) producing `-3521460`.  That's 0xffca444c in DX:AX, so AX = 0x444c (which as a signed int16_t represents +0x444c = 17484 because the high bit is zero).  If you don't get that, single-step with a debugger to verify AX and BX before the `imul`.  (Reposted this comment for a typo, pretty much same as earlier.)

Comment: BTW, `char` is normally signed in x86 C ABIs, but 0x72 is signed-positive so your asm zero-extending it is compatible with what C compilers would do when promoting `x` to `int`.